# unable to locate dockerfile-dev

Tags: docker-compose

I am trying to use docker to use its container for microservices, But unable to get locate the Dockerfile and i saw many blogs but still unclear.

I am following this tutorial.

https://testdriven.io/courses/microservices-with-docker-flask-and-react/part-one-docker-config/

The command i used is.
$ docker-compose -f docker-compose-dev.yml build

The content of Docker-compose-dev file is.

```
version: '3.3'

services:

  users:
    build:
      context: ./
      dockerfile: Dockerfile-dev
    volumes:
      - './:/usr/src/app'
    ports:
      - 5001:5000
    environment:
      - FLASK_APP=project/__init__.py
      - FLASK_ENV=development
```

The content of Dockerfile-dev is.

```
# base image
FROM python:3.7.2-alpine

# set working directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# add and install requirements
COPY ./requirements.txt /usr/src/app/requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# add app
COPY . /usr/src/app

# run server
CMD python manage.py run -h 0.0.0.0
```

I run the command in the path.

```
C:\Users\testdriven-app\services\users\project
```

Exact Error is:

```
Building users..
Error: Cannot locate the specified Dockerfile: Dockerfile-dev
```

[image]

Comment: Is your `docker-compose-dev.yml` and `Dockerfile-dev` file in same location?

Comment: No the docker-compose is in project directory and dockerfile in users directory. @Rash

Comment: So that could potentially be your issue. In your docker-compose file you are setting the context to `context: ./` which means current directory, so you need to place your dockerfile in the same location.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In your `Docker-compose-dev` file, you are setting `context: ./` to current directory, which is not the place your Dockerfile is located at. Context in docker-compose build means [[Source]](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v2/#context):

> Either a path to a directory containing a Dockerfile, or a url to a git repository.

The `dockerfile` option tells you the name of the Dockerfile that must be present in the context.

When you tell docker-compose about your context, you are essentially saying to Docker Engine that "this is my directory which I am giving you access to, and you will find all the files needed to build my image inside this directory".